# I want to make a script in Google sheet to find and match strings of texts between different sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working on a Google sheet script to manage stocks of items in a game, which is supposed to work as such:

People can make request to deposite or withdraw items using a Google form, which send all the infos, including what resource and in what amount, to a first "log" sheet. I then want a script to read these logs, and use them to update a different sheet, which show the actual stocks.

I should mention, there's about 800 different items to stock, and we like to move them around (up or down the list) because we're dumb.

So my idea what the have the script first retrieve the name of the item we made a request for, then try to match it in the stock sheet.

**If it can**, it should then add or substract the amount to the stock.

**If it can't**, it should just colour the log line in red so we can see it and redo the request.

My first problem is that I have no idea if a script in Gsheet can stay active for a long time, and the second is that I have even less of an idea how to properly retrieve a string of text and store it, then compare it with others, and that +800 times each time.

Thank you !

Comment: @Ruben's answer is fine if you want to learn this from basics. But if you want to see a couple examples how it could be done you have to provide more details. How your form looks like. How your destination table looks like. Workflow, names, columns — a possible solution depends on it.

Comment: Well, it's not that I don't want to provide more details, it's just that I have no idea what else to tell you :/

For this script, it would basically be 2 sheets, and in each, a column the script has to be able to "read". One column, in the "log" sheet, is empty at the beginning, then get filled a line at a time everytime someone send a report of depositing/withdrawing something in the stock. What is written is the resource that was taken, for exemple, "Coal". The amount of said resource is put in another column, on the same line.

1/2

Comment: 2/2

The script take that text, then goes to the column in the second sheet, called "stock". That column contain every different item we can have in stock. The script then have to see if it can find a match for what was written in "log". If it can, it then add/substract the amount from what was already in stock.

As for Ruben's answer, it's already very helpful, especially for the explanation about execution, so I'm gonna start with that. But if you have anymore idea, I would gladly hear them ! I'm terrible with language, so anything helps.

Thank you

Comment: Okay. But it would be way more clearer if you try to create the two tables (manually), just 3-5 rows would be enough to illustrate the idea: the log table and the destination table. And add these screenshots (or, even better, markdown tables) into your question.

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add a table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure.  If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455/) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example how it could be done for simplest case, for manual firing of the functions.

Let's say you have the log sheet that look like this:

[image]

And your data sheet looks like this:

[image]

Here is the function that takes all items from the log sheet, sums them and put on the data sheet:

```
function add_all_items_from_log() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var log = ss.getSheetByName('log').getDataRange().getValues();

  // put all data into the object {item1:q, item2:q, item3:q, ...etc}
  var obj = {};
  for (let [date, item, q] of log) {
    if (item in obj) obj[item] += q; else obj[item] = q;
  }
  console.log(obj);

  // convert the object into a 2d array [[item1,q], [item2,q], [item3,q], ...]
  var array = Object.keys(obj).map(key => [key, obj[key]]);
  console.log(array);
  
  // put the array on the data sheet (starting from second row)
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('data');
  sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow()).clearContent();
  sheet.getRange(2,1,array.length, array[0].length).setValues(array);
}
```

The result:

[image]

Here is the function that takes item from the last line of the log sheet and add the item to the data sheet:

```
function add_last_item_from_log() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // get item from the last row of the log sheet
  var [date, item, q] = ss.getSheetByName('log').getDataRange().getValues().pop();
  console.log(date, item, q);

  // get data from the data sheet
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('data');
  var [header, ...data] = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  
  // put the data into the object {item1:q, item2:q, item3:q, ...etc}
  var obj = {};
  data.forEach(row => obj[row[0]] = row[1]);
  console.log(obj);

  // add the item to the object
  if (item in obj) obj[item] += q; else obj[item] = q;
  
  // convert the object into a 2d array [[item1,q], [item2,q], [item3,q], ...]
  var array = Object.keys(obj).map(key => [key, obj[key]]);
  console.log(array);

  // put the array on the sheet (starting from second row)
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('data');
  sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow()).clearContent();
  sheet.getRange(2,1,array.length, array[0].length).setValues(array);
}
```

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11K9iOIJXEvHCa5xB-tgqgES90dZxPfo3IRQ3iiglfks/edit?usp=sharing) is my sheet.

You can run these function manually from Text Editor. Just to see how it works. But actually, as far as I can tell, you better to run the last function (or its variant) automatically every time the log sheet is updated from the Form submit. It can be done with the trigger `onFormSubmit()`.

And this is a simplest case. If you have 800+ items and many columns the code may require some optimizations.

Answer (score 1):

From the question

> My first problem is that I have no idea if a script in Gsheet can stay active for a long time,

Google Apps Script have quotas. In this case, the corresponding quota is the execution time limit. For free accounts the limit is 6 minutes, for Workspace accounts the limit is 30 minutes.

> and the second is that I have even less of an idea how to properly retrieve a string of text and store it, then compare it with others, and that +800 times each time.

Start by reading https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets

Tl;Dr.

1. You need to learn the pretty basics of JavaScript.
2. You might use the Spreadsheet Service (Class SpreadsheetApp) or the Advanced Sheets Service, i.e.

   ```
   /**
    * Returns the values from the data range of the active sheet
    *
    */
   function readData(){
      const sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
      const values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
      return values;
   }
   ```

You should decide where do you will store the values, then use JavaScript comparison expressions. You might use loops (for, while, do..while, or use Array methods like Array.prototype.forEach()